# How to specify padding with keras in Conv2D layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement [AlexNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlexNet) with Keras and was inspecting the network design in MATLAB which is given as follows

[image]

As could be seen, the second convolution layer has 256 filters of size 5x5,  48 channels and a padding of [ 2 2 2 2 ]. How could I specify `padding` of [ 2 2 2 2] with Keras? I went through the [documentation of Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d). It accepts only 2 values for padding namely `valid` and `same`. I could not understand this. For what I know, `valid` would mean zero padding. How could I specify [2 2 2 2] padding with the second convolution layer? I created the first layer as:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 96, kernel_size = (11,11), 
 strides = (4,4), padding = "valid", input_shape=(227,227,3)))
```

Also, since in the second layer there are 48 channels, do I need to be explicit about it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A specific padding isn't specified in `Conv2D` but instead a `ZeroPadding2D` layer.

`valid` and `same` are really just shorthands for common paddings - `valid` means that you don't pad the input and `same` means you add padding such that the output length is the same as the input length.

In your case if you wanted to add a specific padding of size 2:

```
model.add(keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(2, 2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 96, kernel_size = (11,11), strides = (4,4), padding = "valid"))
```

I would also strongly suggest checking out this [keras implementation of alexnet](https://github.com/eweill/keras-deepcv/blob/master/models/classification/alexnet.py). Note that you can also find docs for padding layers in [the keras convolutional docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) (it's all the way at the bottom).

Comment: What does it really mean to pad with 2 2 2 2 and then use `padding=same` in the Conv2D?

Comment: @SuhailGupta same will give you more padding, each time you pass through a conv layer your output gets smaller unless you pad. If you pad with 2 2 2 2, your input gets bigger. Then it's passed into your conv layer and then same/valid affect it in the manner that I described above.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Your (2 2 2 2) should correspond to ((top_pad, bottom_pad), (left_pad, right_pad)), which is the same as `ZeroPadding2D(padding=(2, 2))`.

Comment: What difference would it make if I do not add [2 2 2 2] padding and directly use `same`?

Comment: @SuhailGupta `same` has to do with the size of the kernel, while `ZeroPadding2D` does not. `same` only ensures that the input has the same shape as the output. In AlexNet this isn't always the case. The only situation when [2 2 2 2] padding is equivalent to `same` is if your `kernel_size = (3, 3)`

Comment: @SuhailGupta run this code an examine how the output shape changes depending on the padding for it to be more clear: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qacL5Moe_ELtKIrEbVJyvZUq-oPLsT1t

Comment: @Primusa that's not true, padding `1` is equivalent to `same` when kernel size is `3` and padding `2` when kernel size is `5`. AlexNet uses same padding everywhere, check link in my answer

Comment: @SzymonMaszke But I said exactly what you said... "the only situation when [2 2 2 2] padding is equivalent to same is if your kernel_size = (3, 3)" ... "same has to do with the size of the kernel, while ZeroPadding2D does not"

Comment: Padding `[1 1 1 1]` is equivalent to `same` for kernel size `(3,3)`, not padding `[2 2 2 2]` as you say.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Oh you're correct that's my bad, but everything else stands

Comment: Indeed it does, better to give consistent view throughout our two complementary answers though.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke yeah, another point of disconnect is when you say AlexNet uses same padding all around - I think this is the case for all layers except for the first one , I am using (http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture9.pdf) as my source

Comment: It will be helpful to future readers, if you could put up in your answer the role of `ZeroPadding2D` with AlexNet and also if there exists any relation between `ZeroPadding2D` and the padding attribute of `Conv2D`

Answer (score 3):

You got `valid` padding right, please notice that width and height will be smaller after layer with this parameter.

Padding `same` on the other hand means that specific padding size will be used to ensure image dimensions **will not** change.

For your specific case, if you pad input image with `2` pixels on each side you will get exactly same size of image as output from the layer. So specifying `same` will perform exact same padding as `[2 2 2 2]`.

If you want formula for calculating output size after convolutional layer [check first answer to this Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-calculate-the-size-of-output-of-convolutional-layer).

I have rarely (if at all) seen different padding schemes so those usually suffice.

BTW. All layers in AlexNet use padding `same` except the first one (as correctly pointed out in the comments to another  answer).