# CNN architechture

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have to build a CNN architecture. The following is the code which I used to implement the CNN architecture.
[image]

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (7,7),padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(96,96,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='valid',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='valid',activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
```

What I am confused with is about the padding in the Convolutional layers where the padding is required. The CNN architecture mentions `+1 padding`. I am confused how shall I mention that in this architecture using Keras. All I found padding in Keras to be `same`,`valid`. I want to confirm if my code where I mentioned `padding=same` will do the same thing as mentioned in the picture of the CNN architecture.

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55695396/14293274)? If your codebase is not too big you could switch to PyTorch - there you can specify the padding more intuitively (and PyTorch already pretty much took over the lead from TensorFlow anyway)

Comment: You could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112123/how-to-give-padding-6-in-tensorflow-2-0)