# Adding a Dropout layer in CNN after the dense causes shape error

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have the following CNN code. The model works perfectly fine without the `Dropout` layer after the first dense layer. However, adding a `Dropout` layer throws the below error when I call `model.fit()` with `train_generator`.

```
Input to reshape is a tensor with 3444736 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 20736
 [[node sequential/flatten/Reshape (defined at \SOURAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9752/3078376734.py:1) ]] 
 [Op:__inference_train_function_1328]
```

The CNN code is below

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1),input_shape=(96,96,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32,(7,7),activation='relu',padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),activation='relu',padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='valid',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='valid',activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) # adding this layer throws the above error. 
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
```

This is the [`model.summary()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKL5x.png). I would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Do you need to use `ZeroPadding2D()`? You're getting tensor shape mismatches. `Dropout()` shouldn't really cause that.

Comment: Yes I need to specify a padding of 1. Now according to my research I found out that that if I need to specify custom padding it should be done with zero padding. If there is any other any to specify custom padding please let me know. However, when I remove Dropout this architecture works fine. Please advice

Comment: Is your input data shape (94, 94, 3), (96, 96, 3), or (98, 98, 3)? `Conv2D()` has padding built into it without changing the starting input shape. Try changing `valid` to `same`, move your input shape parameter to the first convolutional layer using the input shape that matches your data, comment the padding layers. After each padding layer, the input shape is increased by (2, 2, 0). `Conv2D`'s padding only pads as necessary.

Comment: The architecture of the CNN can be found in the link below.The input of the image is (96,96,3). If you notice the architecture in the link then it says I need Convolutional layer with padding +1 which is why I have added a ZeroPadding2D


  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059868/cnn-architechture

Comment: The +1 padding comes from using `same` and a stride of 2. Just use the padding in `Conv2D`.

Comment: `ZeroPadding2D` is +2 padding because it pads +1 to every each side of the dimensions, so left +1, right +1, top +1, bottom +1. `Conv2D` just pads to the end of the stride.

Comment: Or if you just have to use `ZeroPadding2D`, you'll need to figure out how to remove one of the padded zeros from each dimension. Also `ZeroPadding2D` *always* pads. `Conv2D` only pads as necessary.

Comment: So if I do padding = same , strides=(2,2) in Conv2D it will be the same as padding +1 mentioned in the link of the CNN architecture I provided?

Comment: It depends. It would be a lot easier if you knew how the output shape of each layer is *supposed* to look. I noticed you're using a filter size 7, so `padding="same"` would pad more than +1. Does it work if you just padded through the convolutional layer? If I were making that model from that image, I wouldn't have originally picked
`ZeroPadding` but now I can see why you did.